# Kotlin: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: kotlin, exception, casting, long-integer

I know there are a lot of questions about this exception but no answer suited my case.

```
var count = sharedPref.getInt("flutter.badgeCount", 0)    // line 12
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(applicationContext, count+1)    // line 13
```

`count` should be an integer because `sharedPref.getInt` returns an integer, and `applyCount()` receive an integer as the second parameter. The exception is thrown at runtime at line 12.
Is there anything I can't see? (I'm pretty new to kotlin)

Comment: You must have a long value stored in the shared preferences for that key.

Comment: "because sharedPref.getInt returns an integer" _if it succeeds_. In your case it fails, so the stored value is not an integer (and from the error message we know it's a long). Line 13 doesn't matter because you never get to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following. This would solve the problem.

```
var count = sharedPref.getLong("flutter.badgeCount", 0L)  
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(applicationContext, count.toInt()+1)
```

Comment: I got an error: "Type mismatch: inferred type is Long but Int was expected".

Comment: Ok, I cast `count` to integer with `count.toInt()` and now works fine